# Combining vectors of unequal length and non-unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, missing-data

I would like to do the following:

combine into a data frame, two vectors that

- have different length
- contain sequences found also in the other vector
- contain sequences not found in the other vector
- sequences that are not found in other vector are never longer than 3 elements
- always have same first element

The data frame should show the equal sequences in the two vectors aligned, with NA in the column if a vector lacks a sequence present in the other vector.

For example:

```
vector 1    vector 2                     vector 1        vector 2
   1           1                            a               a
   2           2                            g               g
   3           3                            b               b
   4           1            or              h               a
   1           2                            a               g
   2           3                            g               b   
   5           4                            c               h
               5                                            c
```

should be combined into data frame

```
    1   1                                    a   a
    2   2                                    g   g
    3   3                                    b   b
    4   NA                                   h   NA
    1   1                  or                a   a 
    2   2                                    g   g
    NA  3                                    NA  b
    NA  4                                    NA  h
    5   5                                    c   c
```

What I did, is to search for merge, combine, cbind, plyr examples but was not able to find solutions. I am afraid I will need to start write a function with nested for loops to solve this problem.

Comment: A *sequence* by definition is an ordered list of objects. Take two sequences, e.g. `c("apple", "banana")` and `c("apple", "orange")`: we know from sequence #1 that `banana` will come after `apple`; similarly, we know from sequence #2 that `orange` will come after `apple`. But what will tell us if `banana` or `orange` should come first? We need a way to sort elements across multiple sequences. Can you clarify that aspect of the problem? (In your example, you used integers for which there is an implicit solution. Maybe it's just a matter of confirming that your two vectors are `integer`.)

Comment: Do both vectors contain the same number of sequences? Is there a special value that always indicate the start of a new sequence (`1` in your example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maintain that your problem might be solved in terms of the [shortest common supersequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence). It assumes that your two vectors each represent *one* sequence. Please give the code below a try.

If it still does not solve your problem, you'll have to explain  exactly what you mean by "my vector contains not one but many sequences": define what you mean by a sequence and tell us how sequences can be identified by scanning through your two vectors.

**Part I**: given two sequences, find the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

```
LongestCommonSubsequence <- function(X, Y) {
    m <- length(X)
    n <- length(Y)
    C <- matrix(0, 1 + m, 1 + n)
    for (i in seq_len(m)) {
        for (j in seq_len(n)) {
            if (X[i] == Y[j]) {
                C[i + 1, j + 1] = C[i, j] + 1
            } else {
                C[i + 1, j + 1] = max(C[i + 1, j], C[i, j + 1])
            }
        }
    }

    backtrack <- function(C, X, Y, i, j) {
        if (i == 1 | j == 1) {
            return(data.frame(I = c(), J = c(), LCS = c()))
        } else if (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) {
            return(rbind(backtrack(C, X, Y, i - 1, j - 1),
                         data.frame(LCS = X[i - 1], I = i - 1, J = j - 1)))
        } else if (C[i, j - 1] > C[i - 1, j]) {
            return(backtrack(C, X, Y, i, j - 1))
        } else {
            return(backtrack(C, X, Y, i - 1, j))
        }
    }

    return(backtrack(C, X, Y, m + 1, n + 1))
}
```

**Part II**: given two sequences, find the [shortest common supersequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence)

```
ShortestCommonSupersequence <- function(X, Y) {
    LCS <- LongestCommonSubsequence(X, Y)[c("I", "J")]
    X.df <- data.frame(X = X, I = seq_along(X), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Y.df <- data.frame(Y = Y, J = seq_along(Y), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   
    ALL <- merge(LCS, X.df, by = "I", all = TRUE)
    ALL <- merge(ALL, Y.df, by = "J", all = TRUE)
    ALL <- ALL[order(pmax(ifelse(is.na(ALL$I), 0, ALL$I),
                          ifelse(is.na(ALL$J), 0, ALL$J))), ]
    ALL$SCS <- ifelse(is.na(ALL$X), ALL$Y, ALL$X)
    ALL
}
```

**Your Example**:

```
ShortestCommonSupersequence(X = c("a","g","b","h","a","g","c"),
                            Y = c("a","g","b","a","g","b","h","c"))
#    J  I    X    Y SCS
# 1  1  1    a    a   a
# 2  2  2    g    g   g
# 3  3  3    b    b   b
# 9 NA  4    h <NA>   h
# 4  4  5    a    a   a
# 5  5  6    g    g   g
# 6  6 NA <NA>    b   b
# 7  7 NA <NA>    h   h
# 8  8  7    c    c   c
```

(where the two updated vectors are in columns `X` and `Y`.)

Comment: If receivers recorded perfectly, the two vectors would be the shortest common supersequence. But they are not perfect. For each element in SCS, there is a probability that it will not be in my vector. Therefore, my vectors are subsets of SCS. I need to find out which elements from SCS are missing in each vector and put NA instead. 

I will review your code later flodel, you have been patient and helpful, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. The columns `X` and `Y` of the example above match exactly your expected output. Can you explain why you think this algorithm won't work for you? Or in other words, can you explain why you think the example you provided is not representative of your problem...? Also why don't you just give a sample of your data? I've been patient because you have one of the most interesting problems I've seen on SO for a while, but I'll admit I'll be running out soon :-)

Comment: I did not say it will not work. I just did not have time to test it.

Comment: I have been able to test your solution and it worked, so I will accept your answer. Thanks for all the trouble! Those Wikipedia links revealed that I was thinking of a sequence as a substring, but apparently they are not the same. One problem with your solution is the need to create m+1 by n+1 matrix. For large X and Y, I get "too many elements specified" matrix related error. I guess I'd need to take a look at the Large memory and out-of-memory data page at CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: The reason I did not give sample of my data is that it is even more complicated... Each vector is in fact a _paste_ of multiple columns. Additionally, there are 40,000 observations and only 40 or so observations missing. And... And... Therefore I provided the simplest representation of my problem to you, and I will concern myself with the implementation issues.

Answer (score 6):

**Note** - this was proposed as an answer to the first version of the OP. The question has been modified since then but the problem is still not well-defined in my opinion.

---

Here is a solution that works with your `integer` example and would also work with `numeric` vectors. I am also assuming that:

- both vectors contain the same number of sequences
- a new sequence starts where `value[i+1] <= value[i]`

If your vectors are non-numeric or if one of my assumptions does not fit your problem, you'll have to clarify.

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,5)
v2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5)

v1.sequences <- split(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) <= 0)))
v2.sequences <- split(v2, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v2) <= 0)))

align.fun <- function(s1, s2) { #aligns two sequences
  s12 <- sort(unique(c(s1, s2)))
  cbind(ifelse(s12 %in% s1, s12, NA),
        ifelse(s12 %in% s2, s12, NA))
}

do.call(rbind, mapply(align.fun, v1.sequences, v2.sequences))
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    1    1
#  [2,]    2    2
#  [3,]    3    3
#  [4,]    4   NA
#  [5,]    1    1
#  [6,]    2    2
#  [7,]   NA    3
#  [8,]   NA    4
#  [9,]    5    5
```

Comment: Unfortunately both assumptions do not hold for my case. The integers in my case are decimal numbers that are generated randomly.

Comment: @DmitriiI., if your two vectors are `numeric` (what you call "decimal"), why would you have an example with `integer`s, then edit it to add another example with `character`s? Can you just give your real data or a subset of it if it is too much?

Comment: @DmitriiI., if your two vectors have a different numbers of sequences, we need some clarification. Imagine that vector 1 has 5 sequences and vector 2 has 8 sequences. Three (8-5) of the sequences from vector 2 won't have a match. Which ones? The last three?

Comment: @DmitriiI. If my assumption that a new sequence starts where `value[i+1] <= value[i]` is wrong, can you tell us what the rule is? Is it that every sequence starts with the same value (`1` or `a` in your two current examples?)

Comment: I gave example in characters to indicate that data is random and no patterns should be sought in it. Regarding your second comment: I think this is exactly what I am trying to solve. I have some unmatched sequences. I do not know which ones. I want to put NA in the data frame once they are found.

Comment: In my definition, a sequence can also be of length one. Both vectors always start with same sequence, of length n = 1, 2, 3...

Comment: I added to my original question, this fact: sequences that are not found in other vector never exceed length of 3 elements. Therefore, when comparing element by element, you know that if an element in vector one, is not in the next three elements of vector 2, than vector 2 is missing this element.

Comment: Using the current implementation of factor, you could create common factor levels, then the character example can be converted to the integer solution.

Comment: @DmitriiI. I can tell you are struggling defining your problem. Here is a well-formed problem that seems pretty close to yours, can you tell if it is what you want? *Given two sequences `s1` and `s2` (the two provided vectors), find the [shortest common supersequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence).*

Comment: Perhaps adding real life context will help: I have two receivers recording discrete random signal coming from same source. In theory, both should produce same recordings. Due to imperfections, both receivers, independently, may miss some signals. None of the receivers misses more than 3 consecutive signals. I want to add a row with NA to the signal recordings of a receiver that missed a signal. You only know that a signal was missed by looking at subsequent recorded signals, knowing that at some point they should be synced again.

Comment: The shortest common supersequence is different than my problem, although related. Conceptually, my vector contains not one but many sequences.